# I just am not sure where I am going wrong. Writing a program to print out prime factorization in c and practicing linking along with it

Tags: c

In this program I keep getting a floating point exception at the end. There are two main files I am working with. The first is the "main" listed below:

```
int main(){ 
int ans;
do{
printf("Enter an integer greater than 1:\n");
scanf("%d", &ans);
}while(ans <= 1);

printf("%d = ", ans);

int d = 2;

while(ans >= d){

if(ans == d){
        printf("%d ^ %d", d, factor_power(ans, d));
        ans = ans / (d ^ (factor_power(ans, d)));
}

else{
        printf("%d ^ %d * ", d , factor_power(ans , d));
        ans = ans/(d ^ (factor_power(ans, d)));
        d++;

        }
}

printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

The file that contains the factor_power() method is here:

```
int factor_power(int n, int d){
int p = 1;

do{
if( n % (d ^ p) == 0)
        p ++;
}while(n % (d^(p+1)) == 0);

return p;
}
```

both include my header, math.h, and stdio.h. I am just so lost on where the floating point exception is coming from. The program is supposed to print out the prime factors like:

1200 = 2^4 * 3^1 * 5*2.

Amy feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: oh wow okay, how do you get an int value of taking something to a power of something else  in C? Sorry if that's dumb, I am just beginning to learn C

Comment: E.g `int ipower(int x, int n){/*x^n */
 int result = 1;
 while(n > 0){
  if(n & 1)
   result *= x;
  x = x * x;
  n >>=1;
 }
 return result;
}`

Comment: Downvoted because I think that if you begun to learn C, you should also start to learn how to use a debugger. This problem could be found easily using a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
 int ipow(int base, int exp)
 {
 int power = 1;
 while (exp)
 {
    if (exp & 1)
        power *= base;
    exp >>= 1;
    base *= base;
  }

 return power;
 }


int factor_power(int n, int d){
 int p = 1;

 do{
 if( (n % ipow(d,p)) == 0)
    p++;
 } while((n % ipow(d,(p+1))) == 0);

  return p;
  }
```

You may have to include "math.h" if u already hadn't.

Hope it helps!

Comment: might also be wise to check `exp` is not negative

Comment: @M.M No need as p(exp) is initialized with 1 and increments by 1 with each iteration.